# Laravel send tweet as user

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, send, tweets

Is it possible to send automatic tweets from laravel like user. 
User must be logged by my twitter API, and then can I send tweet as him?Of course he must accept this action. I must know when user tweets my page.
Can it work like facebook share? Is there tools for this?

Sorry for my english. 
Thanks for all answer.

PS.
I do not mean this package http://vegibit.com/send-a-tweet-with-laravel/ .
I need send tweets to user table.

Comment: You can use api tweeter to share message. But if you want keep date user in own database you need add that manualy (Model,Controller,Migration etc).

Comment: `Codebird` libray for `PHP` by Jublo is a good library to implement Twitter Login and other funtionality in you php site. Have a look on below link
https://github.com/jublonet/codebird-php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this https://twitteroauth.com/ package.

Push in your console `composer require abraham/twitteroauth`
When all installed then you should add 
`use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;` to your class.

Now in function you must create connection with your api.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(
CONSUMER_KEY, // Information about your twitter API
CONSUMER_SECRET, // Information about your twitter API
$access_token, // You get token from user, when him  sigin to your app by twitter api
$access_token_secret// You get tokenSecret from user, when him  sigin to your app by twitter api
);
```

If you created connection then you can send post as user.
For example:

```
$connection->post("statuses/update", ["status" => "My first post!"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the ThuJohn package to be the winner at this type of work. 
https://github.com/thujohn/twitter
Simple to use with various options, such as

Send a tweet realtime without media:

```
Route::get('/send-tweet-no-media', function()
{
    return Twitter::postTweet(['status' => 'Laravel is beautiful', 'format' => 'json']);
});
```

Send a tweet realtime with media:

```
Route::get('/send-tweet-with-media', function()
{
    $uploaded_media = Twitter::uploadMedia(['media' => File::get(public_path('filename.jpg'))]);
    return Twitter::postTweet(['status' => 'Laravel is beautiful', 'media_ids' => $uploaded_media->media_id_string]);
});
```

You can also do various other things, such as login, You can take it an extra level and easily store the users token & secret to your users table and do scheduled posts.

Once you have stored the users token & secret you can tweet scheduled posted for them like this:

```
//Get the Users token & from your User Table (or where ever you stored them)
$token = $user->token;
$secret = $user->secret;

//This line resets the token & secret with the users        
Twitter::reconfig(['token' => $token, 'secret' => $secret]);

//This line posts the tweet as the user
Twitter::postTweet(['status' => 'test', 'format' => 'json']);
```